# ASAuthorizationController and sign up / sign in flow

Tags: swift, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

## Context

I have the "Sign Up With Apple" flow working fairly well for my app (Swift code).

I.e. when users visit the app for the first time, it will prompt them to "Sign In With Apple" (which really should be "Sign Up" since I am using the .signUp button) -- that's the 1st screen -- and then continue on by offering the

> Create an account for [app] using your Apple ID "[email]"

and allowing users to choose whether they want to share their email or hide it (using an Apple forward email address). Finally they are asked to enter their password.

All good.

## Problem

However from a flow viewpoint, the "Sign Up" (i.e. creating an account) isn't the only thing that should be available.

So when we've already had the user logged in before and we've stored the opaque user ID provided earlier by the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` I would expect that :

- when I select .signIn for the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` and
- when I provide the following :

  ```
  let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
  request.requestedOperation = .operationLogin
  request.user = fedId
  ```

that the `ASAuthorizationController` would change its wording and not ask the user **again** about

> Create an account for [app] using your Apple ID "[email]"

which is really not what we're hoping users to see.

Is there something I am missing that would allow that flow to be different (i.e. more of a "Sign In" flow) ?

Note : The SignUp flow uses the following

```
    let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
```

which creates *somewhat* of a different look in the 2nd screen (choose email address to share) but it's really not ideal.

Comment: It appears that there's a big experience difference between running the above code in the simulators vs. running on the actual device. The device's flow presents a screen showing "Do you want to sign in to [app] with your Apple ID...". So that would be the expected flow. However I can't get the "Sign Up" flow on my device for some reason.